# ionic align title not working

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making a hybrid app using Ionic and I try to center my page titles using this:

```
<ion-view animation="none" hide-back-button="true" align-title="center" view-title="TITLE">
```

Most of the times when the pages loads, the title is centered, but sometimes the title is positioned to the left, as if it totally ignores the `align-title` attribute. Sometimes, navigating back and forth makes thiss behaviour appear. As you can see, I use `align-title="center"`, and I use this on all pages.

Also, I was thinking about trying `$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center')` which is described on https://codedump.io/share/JpCokgHaEO4/1/force-align-ionic-view-title-to-the-center-using-css and several other pages, but I couldn't find the correct `.config`.

Anyone know the way around this?

Answer (score 0):

To set the alignment programatically you can use the config like this

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform){
   //run code
})
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider){
   $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center') ;
})
```